# are there any good arguments in favour of the unconstitutionality of Mandatory minimum penalties in India?

Tags: india

https://srivastavandco.com/minimum-mandatory-sentences-in-india/

this source is a complete and shortened analysis of mandatory minimum sentances and how it has been dealt with so far along with the author's arguments against it from a constitutional perspective . however there have been contridictory positions too for example this https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thehindu.com/news/national/courts-cant-reduce-minimum-sentence-says-sc/article26231284.ece/amp/

the Indian supreme court has created a doctorine of basic structure which prevents amendmnents to the constitution that are against the basic structure of the constitution

Some of the features of the Constitution termed as "basic" are listed below:

> Supremacy of the Constitution

> Rule of law

> The principle of separation of powers

> The objectives specified in the preamble to the Constitution of India

> Judicial review

> Articles 32 and 226

> Federalism (including financial liberty of states under Articles 282 and 293)

> Secularism

> The sovereign, democratic, republican structure

> Freedom and dignity of the individual
> Unity and integrity of the nation

> The principle of equality, not every feature of equality, but the quintessence of equal justice;

> The "essence" of other fundamental rights in Part III

> The concept of social and economic justice — to build a welfare state: Part IV of the Constitution

> The balance between fundamental rights and directive principles

> The parliamentary system of government
> The principle of free and fair elections

> Limitations upon the amending power conferred by Article 368

> Independence of the judiciary

> Effective access to justice

> Powers of the Supreme Court of India under Articles 32, 136, 141, 142

> Legislation seeking to nullify the awards made in exercise of the judicial power of the state by arbitration tribunals constituted under an act

But it could very well be that this only applies to amendments and not laws

In Maneka gandhi V state of India it was held that a procedure limiting life and personal liberty as per article 21 of the constitution should be just , proportionate and not oppressive or fanciful.Many laws which impose reverse burden of proof and mandatory minimum  penalties seem grossly disproportionate prima facie